# Create proper symlinks in python

Tags: linux, symlink

I want to loop over directories and create symbolic links of these under different names. The intention is to 'mirror' time-step directories.
The code is as follows:

```
import os
import numpy as np

path = 'constant/boundaryData/'

# check dir names

dirs=os.listdir(path)

# select only directories, not files
dirs=[f for f in dirs if os.path.isdir(path+f)]

# create float list from dirs str names
dirs_float = [float(i) for i in dirs]

dirs_sort = np.sort(dirs_float)

len_dirs = len(dirs_sort)

last_time_step = (dirs_sort[-1])

for i in range(1,len_dirs):
    newTime = str(last_time_step+dirs_sort[i])
    # create symbolic link
    os.symlink(path+str(dirs_sort[-i]),path+newTime)
```

It creates links under the correct name, however, these are not proper directories and are not accessible.

What's going wrong with os.symlink?

Comment: Can you tell what `ls -l` of your symlinks shows ?

Comment: It shows `lrwxrwxrwx`. The is actually the same as with the linux `ln -s` procedure

Comment: Symlinks are always 755. Do the symlinks point to the right place? Check `ls -l`.

Comment: Yes, they do point correctly. However, the directories are highlighted red with yellow font. When trying to access it I get the error: `No such file or directory`

Comment: When they are in red, that means they're invalid.